# How to figure out which application is sending a DNS query on OS X?

Tags: macos, dns

Using Wireshark, I found some unusual DNS queries that were ad-related. But I don't know which application was doing this. Is there any way to figure that out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Cocoa apps (most OS X GUI apps) use networking APIs that use the `mDNSResponder` process to handle their DNS queries. Look at the `mDNSResponder(8)` man page for how to get debug information out of it. It involves sending it the INFO, USR1, and USR2 signals, and watching various log streams. That debug information may tell you which processes are making which queries.

Comment: Finally got the key:

`sudo killall -USR1 mDNSResponder`

`sudo syslog -c mDNSResponder -d`

I can find the PID in syslog.